Why do I have a delayed sound in react capacitor ios app
I am attempting to implement a simple shot clock. The app is built using React and capacitor. The clock is intended to play different sounds when the clock reaches different seconds. It works perfectly on web and android versions.
However on iOS the sound always lags one second behind. The countdown only starts when the users clicks the "start" button, and is also paused with a user click.
Sound files are stored in the app, and do not rely on an external download.
Please advise. I have exhausted all options that I could think of. Code for the functional componenet is below. All props are saved in a useState hook in the parent component and passed down.
Thanks to all and have a great day!!


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import { IonIcon } from '@ionic/react';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStorage, MatchInfo } from '../hooks/useStorage';
import buzzer from '../assets/audio/buzzer.wav'
import beep from '../assets/audio/beep-07a.mp3'
import { playOutline, pauseOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import '../scss/clock.scss'

interface ClockData {
  data: MatchInfo
  updateData: (jsonObj: MatchInfo) => Promise<any> | undefined,
  setLocalData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<MatchInfo>>
}

const Clock: React.FC<ClockData> = (props: ClockData) => {
  const { updateData } = useStorage()
  const beepTone = new Audio(beep)
  const buzzerTone = new Audio(buzzer)
  const [timeFoul, setTimeFoul] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    // clock timing function
    if (props.data.startClock && props.data) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
        newObj = {
          ...props.data,
          seconds: props.data.seconds! - 1,
        }
        props.setLocalData(newObj)
        updateData(newObj)
      }, 1000)
      return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [props.data])

  useEffect(() => {
    //default green clock
    if (!props.data.isWarning && props.data.isDanger) {
      let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
      newObj = {
        ...props.data,
        clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockNormal'
      }
      props.setLocalData(newObj)
      updateData(newObj)
    }
  }, [props.data.seconds])

  useEffect(() => {
    //clock warning listener
    if ((props.data.seconds! <= props.data.warningTime!) && (props.data.seconds! > props.data.dangerTime!)) {
      let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
      newObj = {
        ...props.data,
        clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockWarning',
      }
      props.setLocalData(newObj)
      updateData(newObj)
      if (props.data.playSound && props.data.beepPattern === 'single' && (props.data.warningTime === props.data.seconds)) {
        if (props.data.startClock) {
          beepTone.play()
        }
      }
    }
  }, [props.data.seconds])

  useEffect(() => {
    //clock danger listener
    if (props.data.seconds! <= props.data.dangerTime!) {
      let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
      newObj = {
        ...props.data,
        clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockDanger',
      }
      props.setLocalData(newObj)
      updateData(newObj)

      if (props.data.playSound) {
        if (props.data.startClock) {
          beepTone.play()
        }
      }
    }
  }, [props.data.seconds])

  useEffect(() => {
    // time foul listener
    if (props.data.seconds === 0) {
      if (props.data.playSound) {
        buzzerTone.play()
          .then(() => {
            beepTone.pause()
          })
      }
      let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
      newObj = {
        ...props.data,
        clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockNormal',
        startClock: false,
        seconds: props.data.defaultTime
      }
      props.setLocalData(newObj)
      updateData(newObj)
      setTimeFoul(true)
    }
  }, [props.data])


  const startStopClock = async (start: boolean) => {
    let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
    newObj = {
      ...props.data,
      startClock: start,
    }
    setTimeFoul(false)
    props.setLocalData(newObj)
    await updateData(newObj)
  }

  const pushoutCalled = async () => {
    let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
    newObj = {
      ...props.data,
      pushoutCalled: true,
      seconds: props.data.pushoutTime!,
      startClock: false,
      clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockNormal'
    }
    props.setLocalData(newObj)
    await updateData(newObj)
  }

  const resetTimer = async () => {
    let newObj = {} as MatchInfo
    newObj = {
      ...props.data,
      seconds: props.data.defaultTime,
      startClock: false,
      clockClasses: 'clockBorder clockNormal'
    }
    setTimeFoul(false)
    props.setLocalData(newObj)
    await updateData(newObj)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {props.data ?
        <div className={'clockContainer'}>
          <div className='innerContainer'>
            <div className={'clockHolder'}>
              <div className={`${props.data.clockClasses}`}>
                <div className={'clock'}>{props.data.seconds}</div>
              </div>
              {!props.data.startClock ?
                <>
                  {!timeFoul ? <div className={'pauseBox'}><span>Paused</span></div> : null}
                  {timeFoul ? <div className={'foulBox'}><span>Time Foul</span></div> : null}
                </>
                : null
              }
            </div>

            <div className={'clockControls'}>
              <button className={'startBtn'} onClick={() => startStopClock(true)}><IonIcon icon={playOutline}></IonIcon></button>
              <button className={'pauseBtn'} onClick={() => startStopClock(false)}><IonIcon icon={pauseOutline}></IonIcon></button>
            </div>

            <div className='buttonDiv'>
              {props.data.pushoutAllowed && !props.data.pushoutCalled ?
                <div className='pushoutDiv'>
                  <button className={'pushoutButton'} onClick={pushoutCalled}>Push Out</button>
                </div>
                : null
              }

              <div className={'resetDiv'}>
                <button className={'resetBtn'} onClick={resetTimer}>Reset to {props.data.defaultTime}</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Clock;



